# Use Logitech g15 multimedia keyboard with Apple Logic 9

Tags: keyboard, logic

That's what I'd like to do: use my Logitech g15 multimedia keys (stop, pause etc) with Apple Logic 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [Logitech Control Center for OS X](http://www.logitech.com/584/3129). It will allow you to set all the setting for your keyboard, including the stop, play, pause, and volume up/down buttons.